# FOSRESTBundle - How to create a new entity and use an existing one in ManyToOne relationship?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle

I have the following code:

Entity:

```
<?php

class Trigger
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @JMS\Expose
     *
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string Trigger name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Name cannot be blank")
     *
     * @JMS\Expose
     *
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="triggers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     *
     * @JMS\Expose
     * @JMS\MaxDepth(1)
     * @Assert\NotNull(message="User cannot be null")
     */
    private $user;
}

?>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
    /**
     * @param Trigger $trigger
     * @param Request $request
     * @return mixed|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     * @FosView(serializerEnableMaxDepthChecks=true, serializerGroups={"user", "admin"})
     * @ApiDoc(
     *      description="Create a new trigger"
     * )
     * @ParamConverter("trigger", class="Acme\Bundle\SmsBundle\Entity\Trigger", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
     */
    public function addAction(Trigger $trigger, Request $request)
    {
        return $this->processForm($trigger, $request);
    }

    private function processForm(Trigger $trigger, Request $request)
    {
        $statusCode = 204;
        if ($trigger->getId() == null)
        {
            $statusCode = 201;
        }

        if (sizeof($request->get('validationErrors')) == 0) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($trigger);
            $em->flush();

            $response = new Response();
            $response->setStatusCode($statusCode);

            // set the `Location` header only when creating new resources
            if (201 === $statusCode) {
                $response->headers->set('Location',
                    $this->generateUrl(
                        'acme_secured_api_triggers_get', array('id' => $trigger->getId()),
                        true // absolute
                    )
                );
            }

            return $response;
        }

        return View::create($request->get('validationErrors'), 400);
    }
?>
```

I have the following data that I POST to create a new entity: `{"name": "test", "user": {"id": 1}}`.

`User` with ID=1 **does** exist. But I'm getting the following response:

> A new entity was found through the relationship
>   "Acme\Bundle\SmsBundle\Entity\Trigger#user" that was not configured to
>   cascade persist operations for entity:
>   Acme\Bundle\SmsBundle\Entity\User@000000006f774479000000004dc4b500. To
>   solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on
>   this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in
>   the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you
>   cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement
>   "Acme\Bundle\SmsBundle\Entity\User#__toString()" to get a clue.

As one can see, Symfony (Doctrine) doesn't detect that I used an existing user and instead is trying to create a new one (but failing because no cascade persist is set). Are the any ideas on how to overcome this?

Answer (score 3):

you need to ensure that the user entity is managed in the entity manager, either by fetching it or by using the $em->merge() method to get the instance managed by the entity manager

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As such, I realized that the best option for my case would be using Symfony Forms.